# lwip tcp_write does not work

Tags: ftp, lwip

I'm trying to run the FTP server given in the following link but having some problems.

https://github.com/toelke/lwip-ftpd

If the client sends a "LIST" command, the server handles the request in 
 send_next_directory(...) function located in ftpd.c:523 and responds with 226 to close the data connection.

```
static void send_next_directory(struct ftpd_datastate *fsd, struct tcp_pcb *pcb, int shortlist)
{
        char buffer[1024];
        int len;

        while (1) {
        if (fsd->vfs_dirent == NULL)
            fsd->vfs_dirent = vfs_readdir(fsd->vfs_dir);

        if (fsd->vfs_dirent) {

            ....
            ....

        } else {

            ....
            ....

            send_msg(msgpcb, fsm, msg226); // Here
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, even if it reaches that line and calls tcp_write after that, the message is sent sporadically. I've checked the Wireshark. There is no message on the wire %90 of the time.